# How can i simplify this code in kotlin?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I am doing a program and I need to read input from two `.txt` files. But I know there is a simpler a way than duplicating the code. I already wrote this:

```
import java.io.File

fun chamadas (args: Array<String>) {
val ficheiro1 = "voos.txt"
val ficheiro2 = "reservas.txt"

    val linha1 = File(ficheiro1).readLines()
    for (line in linha1) {
        val parts = line.split(':')
        val flightNumber = parts[0]
        val origin = parts[1]
        val destination = parts[2]
        val date = parts[3]
    }

    val linha2 = File(ficheiro2).readLines()
    for (line in linha2) {
        val parts = line.split(':')
        val id = parts[0]
        val nameSurname = parts[1]
        val flightNumber = parts[2]
        val date = parts[3]
  }
}
```

The `.txt` files are of this type:

`voos.txt` -> `<FlightNumber>:<Origin>:<Destination>:<Date>`

`reservas.txt` -> `<ID>:<Name and Surname>:<FlightNumber>:<Date>`

The date won't be in `DD/MM/YYYY` format, it will only be a number ranging from 1-31. Any ideas on how should i simplify the code?

Comment: Make a method...

Comment: select the 1st for loop and assignment, ctrl+alt+M, choose method name, replace the second loop for a call to that method too

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method like the following:

```
fun processFile(path: String) {
    File(path).forEachLine {
        val (flightNumber, origin, destination, date) = it.split(':')
        println("$flightNumber $origin $destination $date")
    }
}
```

This uses several Kotlin features your code doesn't:

- scoped resource management coupled with line-by-line processing (`forEachLine`)
- destructuring assignment

Answer (score 0):

You could try forgoing the extra variable for `line.split(':')` and simply conjoining everything.

```
for (line in linha1) {
    val flightNumber = line.split(':')[0]
    val origin = line.split(':')[1]
    val destination = line.split(':')[2]
    val date = line.split(':')[3]
}
```

Also, instead of making variables for the file names, you could just put it in directly.

```
val linha1 = File("voos.txt").readLines()
```

If you really wanted to go all the way you could also skip the `linha1` and `linha2` assignments and just do this:

```
for (line in File("voos.txt").readLines()) { /*...*/ }
```

But I can't really see any other opportunities for simplification other than eliminating unnecessary variables. (But this is coming from a relatively inexperienced programmer, so...)

Marko Topolnik's answer is more what you're looking for, but I still suggest eliminatin unnecessary variables to simplify.